# How to install Spring Roo add-ons while offline

Tags: installation, spring-roo, offline, add-on

At work, our dev environment is an internal network with no connectivity to the internet.
I'm currently trying to use Spring Roo's database reverse engineer function but can't seem to get the add-on org.springframework.roo.wrapping.mysql-connector-java to install correctly offline. I have tried the following:

1. Following this link [jtds driver addon problem](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-112165.html?s=1d092f47977feda63ab2905ecb0c575e)

   - I used the roobot.xml to find the url for the wrapping.mysql-connector-java and downloaded the jar.
   - According to Roo docs [Roo Docs Packaging & Distribution](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/index.html#simple-addons-packaging) I used the following command to load the osgi jar.
     `roo> osgi start --url file:///<path-to-addon-project/target/<addon-bundle-name>.<version>.jar`
   - But that resulted in the following errors:
     `org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.wrapping.mysql-connector-java[75]: Unable to resolve 75.0: missing requirement [75.0] package; (package=org.slf4j)`
2. We have an internal repo with the slf4j jars but I can't figure out how to configure Roo to point to it.
3. I copied the ROO_HOME of an installation I did on a home computer with the requested mysql add-on but when I tried running it in my work environment I get multiple:
   `Auto-deploy install: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique:...`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a maven repository manager on your dev network and seeding it with all of your dependencies. I was unable to use Spring/Roo offline without it as I kept running into the type of trouble that you are. I used [Sonatype Nexus OSS](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). It was a pain to seed the repository, but it made Roo usable offline. Hope that helps.